# Структура таблицы расписания

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Мне нужно вывести расписание специалистов

Для этого у меня есть 2 таблицы 
1. Сами специалисты specialist

```
specialist_id
name
```

2. Их расписание specialist_schedule_slots

```
slot_id
specialist_id
week_day (Номер дня недели)
start
end
duration
```

В процессе наполнения специалистов может быть около 10 000... 
Если я буду хранить расписание каждого дня недели в таблице specialist_schedule_slots то, там будет как минимум 70 000 записей...
Вопрос заключается в том, можно ли как либо оптимизировать или создать какую то третью таблицу для того, чтобы запрос выборки выполнялся в дальнейшем быстрее ?

Comment: 70 000 записей для любой нормальной СУБД на любой современной машине — это плюнуть и растереть.

Comment: Существует правила нормализации баз данных. Эти правила помогут определить номенклатуру таблиц. Эти правила не операются на быстродействие, но обычно с более менее нормализованными БД работать проще и быстрее. В вашем случае сколько таблиц бы не было, при объединении они дадут все равно 70000 записей. Поле `duration` выглядит лишним.  Если время в расписании одинаковое, то его можно вынести в отдельную таблицу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если кратко и локонично, то: 
**НЕТ.**

На собственном опыте: вплоть до 500k-600k записей обрабатывает в момент, так что париться не над чем.

С уважением и удачи.